# The well-ordering principle implies Zorn's Lemma

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, alternative-proof

I have read and understood proofs for each implication between $AC$, $ZL$, $WO$ except this one. These proofs need about 10 lines each. Can someone share a neat, hopefully short, proof for $WO\implies ZL$?

(obviously not using $AC$ explicitly)

(I already know [this one](http://www.mn.uio.no/math/tjenester/kunnskap/kompendier/acwozl.pdf))

Comment: I suggest writing out what these acronyms, just in case some do not know what you mean.

Comment: There is no neat and short proof. You have to appeal to transfinite recursion.

Comment: Why do you say AC gives ZL using a short proof?

Comment: @user21820 Suppose $\forall x\in X:\exists x'\in X:x'>x$. Let $\gamma$ be Hartogs' ordinal for $X$, pick $x\in X$. Define $x_\alpha$ for $\alpha<\gamma$ as follows: $x_0 = x$, $x_{\alpha^+}=x_\alpha'$, $x_\lambda = \texttt{upper}(\{x_\alpha : \alpha<\lambda\})$. But then $\gamma$ injects into $X$.

Comment: @akkarin: Isn't that using transfinite recursion, as Asaf mentioned? I know he said it concerning your question, but my point is that if you already allow it for ( AC implies ZL ) then you might as well use it for the rest...

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's a fair point. I was just hoping there might be something nice for $WO\implies AC$. But surprisingly, Luiz' answer seems to contradict Asaf's comment? (I didn't have a look in detail yet)

Comment: Ahh, no, it doesn't: The linked proof goes $WO\implies AC\implies ZL$ it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Pedersen's book *Analysis Now* has a proof of their equivalence without using transfinite induction: [Google books](https://books.google.ca/books?id=zNbiBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) (Theorem 1.1.6).

Also note that the proof of $WO\implies AC$ is two lines long, so perhaps it is easier to prove $WO\implies AC\implies ZL$.

Comment: Isn't $WO\implies AC\implies ZL$ exactly what Pedersen does there?

Comment: @akkarin Yes, it is. I just thought this should be mentioned because you asked for a direct proof of $WO\implies AL$. And Pedersen's proof is the same as in a paper by J. Lewin - *A Short proof of Zorn's Lemma* ([JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2323807)).